# Using $? in an if statement

Tags: bash, scripting

```
function foo {
   (cd $FOOBAR;
   <some command>
   if [$? -ne 0]
   then
      echo "Nope!"
   else
      echo "OK!"
   fi
   )
}
```

I am trying to write a function like the one above and place it in my .bashrc file.  After I source the file and run, I get:

> Total time: 51 seconds
>   -bash: [1: command not found
>   OK!

Can someone help me understand what I did wrong?

Comment: Testing if `$?` is equal to 0 with an `if` statement is pointless, `if` expects a command and _if_ said command returns `0`, it runs the code in the block. so `if true; then echo hello; fi` will echo hello since the command `true` returned `0`.

Comment: @llua It's not pointless. `$?` holds the status of the last *pipeline*, which is not the `test` (`[`) command in the `if` statement. The example is testing whether `some command` was successful. You can do the same with `&&` and `||`, but it can make long, unreadable lines compared to `if [ $? -eq 0 ]`. The same argument goes for `if some command`

Comment: @bonsaiviking I am well aware of what `$?` expands to, i am pointing out there is no point in the `test` being used; since `if some command` does the same thing with one statement versus having two separate statements. if the command is already long, adding three more characters wouldn't make the 'unreadable' terribly more 'unreadable'.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Add a space after the `[`, and another before `]`:

```
function foo {
   (cd "$FOOBAR";
   <some command>
   if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
   then
      echo "Nope!"
   else
      echo "OK!"
   fi
   )
}
```

`[` is a shell builtin, it is a command just like `echo`, `read`, `expr`... it needs a space after it, and requires a matching `]`.

Writing `[ "$?" -ne 0 ]` is actually invoking `[` and giving it 4 parameters: `$?`,  `-ne`, `0`, and `]`.

*Note: the fact that you are getting an error saying `[1: command not found` means that `$?` was having the value of `1`.*

Comment: I just verified that your answer is correct on my Linux VM.

Comment: `[` is a link to `test` as well

Comment: @RickyBeam in most shells, `[` is a shell builtin, and the `/usr/bin/[` is rarely used.

Answer (score 21):

Or you could skip `$?` altogether.  If your command is `cmd`, the following should work:

```
function foo {
   (cd $FOOBAR;
   if cmd
   then
      echo "OK!"
   else
      echo "Nope!"
   fi
   )
}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's good practice to assign the return value to a variable before using it

```
retval="$?"
if [ $retval -ne 0 ]
```

It allows you to reuse the return value. e.g. in an if... elif... else... statement.

Comment: :) Could you expand your answer a bit. Why is it good practice? What kind of errors could be avoided?

Comment: @terdon it's bad practice to use `$?` directly because that will break if you ever, when editing the script later, put a line between the command and the `$?` check.

Comment: @terdon It allows the return value to be reusable. e.g. in an if... elif...else... statement

Comment: I meant, please add this to your answer to make it more complete. We like longer, more detailed answers here.

Comment: This is not good practice if the command's exit status is only going to be used once, which is true in the majority of cases. Indirection with little reason is the root of almost all evil.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason why you'd want to use `$?` as arguments to a `[` command (whether that `[` command is run in the condition part of an `if` statement or not) is when you want to discriminate on a specific return status, like:

```
until
  cmd
  [ "$?" -gt 1 ]
do
  something
done
```

The syntax for all those `if`, `while`, `until`... statements is

```
if cmd-list1
then cmd-list2
else cmd-list3
fi
```

Which runs `cmd-list2` if `cmd-list1` is successful or `cmd-list3` otherwise.

The `[ "$?" -eq 0 ]` command is a no-op. It sets `$?` to 0 if `$?` is 0, and `$?` to non-zero if it was non-zero.

If you want run something if `cmd` failed, it's:

```
if ! cmd
then ...
fi
```

Generally, you don't need to tinker with `$?` let alone know which value means `true` or `false`. The only cases are as I said above if you need to discriminate on a specific value, or if you need to save it for later (for instance to return it as the return value of a function) like:

```
f() {
  cmd; ret=$?
  some cleanup
  return "$ret"
}
```

Also remember that leaving a variable unquoted is the split+glob operator. It doesn't make sense to invoke that operator here, so it should be:

```
[ "$?" -ne 0 ]
```

not <strike>`[ $? -ne 0 ]`</strike>, let alone <strike>`[$? -ne 0 ]`</strike> (which would only invoke the `[` command if `$IFS` happened to contain the first character of `$?`).

Also note that the Bourne way to define a function is to stick `function-name()` in front of a command. That's the case in every Bourne like shell except `bash` and [`yash`](http://yash.sourceforge.jp/index.html.en) (and recent versions of `posh`) which only allow a compound command (compound commands being `{...}` or `(...)` or things like `for...done`, `if...fi`...

`function foo { ... }` is the `ksh` function definition syntax. There's no reason why you'd want to use it here.

Your code can be portably (POSIXly) written:

```
foo() (
  cd -P -- "$FOOBAR" || return # what if the cd failed!
  if
    <some command>
  then
    echo 'OK!'
  else
    echo 'Nope!'
  fi
)
```

Also note that `cd` without `-P` has a very special meaning (handles paths that contain `..` components differently from any other command), so it's better to include it in scripts to avoid confusions.

(that function returns `false` if `cd` fails, but not if `<some command>` fails).

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the command below will do everything you want in one line.

```
(( verify = $?!=0?'Nope!':'OK!' ))
```

Comment: Jeight: Are there missing spaces in your text, above?

Comment: You can't assign strings to variables in arithmetic expressions. In ksh (where that syntax comes from), you can do `(( value_of_A_char = 'A' ))` like in C (where `'A'` will be 65 on ASCII-based systems), but that's about it.